# Ubuntu 14.04.5 Audit mv Command

Tags: 14.04, security, rename

So when I run strace on mv, it shows that it calls rename.

I'm not getting audit events for 'rename' system call. I think I know why and would like some help figuring out a solution.

I have a bunch of audit rules (trying to configure system for JSIG Compliance). One of them is for rename (... -S rename ...). The other rules in a similar format work fine.

On my system, rename is a link to /etc/alternatives/rename, which is a link to /usr/bin/prename. prename is a perl script. My guess that mv is calling prename, which doesn't appear to generate audit events.

Does that make sense? Is this a Ubuntu specific issue?
How do generate audit events for rename to meet my security requirements?
I checked and don't have any alternatives to rename on my system.

Any comments or advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: *"Does that make sense?"* not really - the presence of various user-space programs that happen to be called `rename` should have no effect on the kernel -space syscall `rename`. I don't have any experience with `auditd` but I wonder if you need to add `-S renameat` and/or `-S renameat2` on modern kernels?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I renamed /usr/bin/rename to something else and did a mv on a file and it ran. I wanted to prove to myself that you are in fact correct. I already audit renameat, not sure about renameat2, for when I run strace on the mv command it show rename being called. I have many similar audit rules that appear to work, but not the one for rename. Sigh!

Comment: OK that's certainly a useful data point. If you're already checking for `renameat`/`reanameat2` then I don't know what else to suggest - you may find a more suitable audience for this over on unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

So, as steeldriver pointed out and I proved to myself, the kernel-space syscall rename is different than the 'rename' command. It turns out the real issue was that I had an incorrect audit rule that saying to never audit rename (and may others) before the rule that audit rename. Thanks for the responses, they helped me change my focus and find the real problem. Sigh!